# Is there software to draw in 3D the house framing?

Tags: framing, renovation, software

I want to be able to visualize and explain the specific and rather complex area that will need a rebuild. I don't care about colors or textures or anything, I just want to illustrate studs and plates and beams and rafters and so on.

Trying to address dry rot on zero budget (i.e. materials only) and an illustration would help when asking for advice.

Comment: What is your CAD experience level? This is doable in any number of free CAD packages but there's a steep learning curve. Often it's easier for most folks to draft it on paper.

Answer (score 1):

For your expressed purposes, the free version of [SketchUp](https://www.sketchup.com/try-sketchup#for-personal) which may be useful. It is known to be relatively easy to use and my limited experience bears that out. Additionally, the online resources for help, including video tutorials will provide support for the tricky parts.

As an example, one might draw a rectangle on the "floor" representing the wall's base plate, then extrude it to a suitable height. This creates a two-surface wall on which one can draw rectangles representing studs and extrude from one wall to the other.

Not known to be particularly easy to use, but for your simpler tasks, [Fusion 360 hobbyist](https://accounts.autodesk.com/Authentication/LogOn?viewmode=iframe&ReturnUrl=https://www.autodesk.com/products/fusion-360/personal-form) version will also provide for your requirements. The workflow is quite a bit different from SketchUp but in my opinion, no more difficult to learn for the construction. The steps are similar to that above, but the execution is going to be different, of course. No shortage of tutorials and resources for Fusion 360. Note that the download of the license generates a free trial version of the paid software, which reverts to the free hobbyist version on expiration. This can be misleading to some.

Answer (score -1):

"Home Designer / Chief Architect" would be a good choice if you don't want to be extruding raw 3D rectangles into studs and walls. It's domain-specific and has a relatively easy learning curve. You can accomplish a lot using just a few YouTube tutorials.

Comment: Why the downvote, incidentally?